# помощь по сайту

Tags: php, html

Номер и имя  человека мне приходит в data.txt, но прикрепленные файлы не приходят, опишите пожалуйста подробно что сделать что бы они тоже приходили
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам log.php

```
<?php



$BASE="data.txt";

$IS_EMAIL=false;

$LOCATION="";

$p1=$_REQUEST["number"];

$p2=$_REQUEST["name"];

$p3=$_REQUEST["file"];

$headers = "";

$info="$p1:$p2:$p3:\n";



if ($IS_EMAIL){

mail($BASE, $headers.$info);

} else {

$fd=fopen($BASE,"a+");

fwrite($fd,$info);

fclose($fd);

}

header("Location:$LOCATION");

?>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: так тут фильтры стоят, не получилось

Answer (score 0):

Все данные о передаваемых файлах содержатся в суперглобальном массиве `$_FILES`
Документация вам в помощь http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php